# Fastapi: unique a field in the mysql table for create fastapi

Tags: mysql, sqlalchemy, unique, fastapi

I am trying to build an api by fastapi, connected to mysql.

```
from pydantic import BaseModel 

class User (BaseModel ):
    name : str
    email: str
    password: str
---------------------------------------------------------

from sqlalchemy import Table,Column
from sqlalchemy.sql.sqltypes import Integer,String
from db import *

users= Table(
    'users',meta, 
    Column('id', Integer,primary_key=True),         
    Column('name', String(255),unique=True,index=True),           
    Column('email', String(255)),          
    Column('password', String(255))          )

meta.create_all(engine)
```

I want the field `name` to be unique.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You have the correct syntax to create a UNIQUE index on your `name` column.

But, if you use `utf8mb4` as your character set and an older version of MySQL you may hit a limitation.  In that case the longest column that can be completely indexed is `VARCHAR(191)` or `String(191)`. Those older versions of MySQL have a limit of 767 *bytes* on an indexed column. `utf8mb4` characters take up to four bytes per character. `Math.floor(767/4)` equals 191.

If your field is too long you'll get a prefix index. That compromises the index's ability to enforce uniqueness.

Writeup here. https://www.plumislandmedia.net/index-wp-mysql-for-speed/wordpresss-prefix-keys/

Best fix: use MySQL 5.7 or better, or MariaDB 10.3 or better.

Second best fix: change the column size to something <= 191.

Third best fix: use the older `utf8` (also known as `utf8mb3`) character set for the column which must be unique.